# 404 error when deploying angular sample app in production mode

Tags: node.js, angular

Following an Angular tutorial about deploying the app locally in production mode i failed to do so even using the sample app.
Steps:

1. `ng new prod-app`
2. `ng build --prod`
3. `http-server /dist/prod-app`                 <-- Used in tutorial
4. `lite-server --baseDir="dist/prod-proj"`     <-- In Angular Docs

using both servers result in the same behavior, Blank page an a 404 error

### lite-server output:

```
   F:\AngularApps\prod-proj>lite-server --baseDir="dist"
   Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
   ** browser-sync config **
   { injectChanges: false,
     files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
     watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
     server: { baseDir: 'dist', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] }               }
   [Browsersync] Access URLs:
    -------------------------------------
          Local: http://localhost:3000
       External: http://192.168.56.1:3000
    -------------------------------------
             UI: http://localhost:3001
    UI External: http://localhost:3001
    -------------------------------------
   [Browsersync] Serving files from: dist
   [Browsersync] Watching files...
   19.08.16 08:49:20 404 GET /index.html
   19.08.16 08:49:20 404 GET /favicon.ico
```

There is nothing in neither the tutorial nor the docs about any extra configuration, So what am i missing?

Thanks,
Gado

Comment: From the error shown here, it looks like there's something wrong with the paths in your production build. It's trying to find the production files and bundles in an `app` subdirectory. Have you changed the configuration in some way?

Comment: while building the app for production make sure you have set correct base path

Comment: @WillAlexander Yeah! i was trying some suggestion to use --base-href while building. I think i copied the wrong log here, Sorry!. I'll update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your lite-server output you have specified `baseDir="dist"`, change it to `baseDir="dist/prod-proj"`

```
 F:\AngularApps\prod-proj>lite-server --baseDir="dist/prod-proj"
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks man!, In the Doc it's baseDir="dist". Someone should correct that.The http-server doesn't work anyway. But it is working with lite-server now!

Comment: @Gado, I have raised the PR for the same.